# rysnc exclude directory not working

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script that is running to rsync.  I set up --exclude but its ignoring and syncing those folder anway.

```
set -x;
cd $(dir_name $0);
dest="/home/pi/bash_scripts_2/"
export RSYNC_RSH="ssh -q";

#excluding html and man folders
for dir in html man; do
   rsync -hav ./$dir/ --exclude 'html/' ./$dir/ $dest$dir/; 
   rsync -hav ./$dir/ --exclude 'man/' ./$dir/ $dest$dir/;
done
```

Comment: Maybe I’m missing something, but if you run `rsync` twice and exclude *different* directories, then won’t each invocation sync the directory the other one excludes?

Comment: Not sure probably.  My thought was once it hits the html directory it would exclude it?

Comment: Yeah, and then `rsync … --exclude 'man/' …` will *not* exclude it, i.e. sync it. Why *are* you running `rsync` twice?

Comment: I just removed man and only left html.  It still copies the files in the html folder.

Comment: Removed the rsync line or the element in the loop?

Comment: now reads `for dir in html; do rsync -hav ./$dir/ --exclude 'html/' ./$dir/ $dest$dir/; done`

Comment: Are you trying to sync `html/` but exclude `html/html/`?

Comment: Also, what are you specifying `./$dir/` as an argument twice?

Comment: What I am trying to do is skip the contents in the `html `folder.  Sync everything in the `/home/mike/bash_scripts_2/` to `/home/pi/bash_scripts_2/` folder excluding `html and man`.

Comment: @user3525290 So… something like `rsync -hav --exclude 'html/' --exclude 'man/' /home/mike/bash_scripts_2/ /home/pi/bash_scripts_2/`? Not sure why you thought to run `rsync` four times.

Comment: I've tried your code and I get the same results.  the contents of `html` and `man` get copied over.

Comment: A place to start would be with a [mcve] -- ie. a script that creates two temporary directories (source and dest), with both `html` and `man` directories in the source as well as some dummy content (could be just empty files), and then rsyncs from that source directory to the destination directory and prints "SUCCESS" or "FAILED" depending on that destination directory's contents. That way people don't need to guess about whether their fixes apply to the details of your use case, but can actually test directly.

Comment: (That said, I'm not sure this question should be here on StackOverflow, vs [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) -- it's not really a question about bash-the-scripting-language, but about command-line rsync use -- rsync being an external tool that isn't part of bash at all).

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is doing four things.

First loop:

```
rsync html/ to dest/html excluding html/ (nothing copied)
rsync html/ to dest/html excluding man/ (html is copied to dest/html)
```

Second loop:

```
rsync man/ to dest/man excluding html/ (man is copied to dest/man)
rsync man/ to dest/man excluding man/ (nothing copied)
```

So overall you're copying both folders.

Comment: I changed the loop to `for dir in html; do`  the contents of the html folder is still being copied.

Comment: Your second rsync command is copying it - it's only excluding `man/`.  If you want to exclude both of these folders use `rsync -hav ./$dir/ --exclude 'html/' --exclude 'man/' ./$dir/ $dest$dir/;`

Comment: Tried that and it still copies the contents of html and man folders

Comment: `sending incremental file list ./ html.txt  created directory /home/pi/bash_scripts_2/man ./ man.txt`  Copied all of the other files as well.  I deleted the man folders thinking it might help but just recreates the folders and copies content.

Comment: Even if i run `rsync -hav /home/mike/bash_scripts_2/ --exclude /home/mike/bash_scripts_2/html/ /home/pi/bash_scripts_2/;` from the command line it still copies the html folder.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be passing **either** `html` or `man` as arguments if you don't want them copied.

Consider the following test setup:

```
mkdir -p src{/html,/man,/do-copy-me} dest
touch src/copy-me src/{html,man}/dont-copy-me src/do-copy-me/yes-really
```

...given it, this works:

```
rsync -hav --exclude=html --exclude=man src/. dest/.
```

Note that we aren't passing `html` or `man` as explicit arguments, but the parent directories that contain them.

You'll observe that `dest` properly contains `do-copy-me/yes-really`, `do-copy-me`, but not `html` or `man`.

Answer (score 0):

I think all I had to do was remove the `/` from the `html/`.  Using the `.` because I do a cd to the current directory.  Still have to hardcode the dest directory.  But this seems to work. will try to use `--exclude-from 'filename.txt'` To clean up the code. Thanks for all help.

```
cd $(dir_name $0);
dest="/home/pi/bash_scripts_2/"
export RSYNC_RSH="ssh -q";

for dir in html man whatever; do
   rsync -hav --exclude 'html' --exclude 'man' --exclude 'whatever' . $dest;
done
```

Comment: You aren't using `$dir` at all. What's the point to the `for` loop?

Comment: ...and btw, you've got some quoting issues here; consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and addressing what it finds.